# web.config encryption & decryption

Tags: asp.net

How can I encrypt a web.config file?
And how can I then decrypt it again?

Comment: do you want to encrypt hole config or only connection strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greetings qablan89 i got you and the code you need is :

```
       //Method for Encryption
       public void EncryptConnectionString(Page Mypage)
        {
            Configuration objConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            ConnectionStringsSection objConnectionString = (ConnectionStringsSection)objConfig.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            if (!objConnectionString.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                objConnectionString.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
                objConnectionString.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                objConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            }
        }

        //Method for Decrypt 
        public void DecryptConnectionString(Page Mypage)
        {
            Configuration objConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~);
            ConnectionStringsSection objConnectionString = (ConnectionStringsSection)objConfig.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            if (objConnectionString.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                objConnectionString.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
                objConnectionString.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                objConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            }
        }
```

Note This code is for the connection string attribute in the webconfig if you specify another one i am here to help

Please dont forget to mark on the answer as a correct one if its useful to you :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting Web.config is a pretty bad idea on first chance.

You surely do store sensitive information like connection strings, but...

1. No user can download Web.config from HTTP
2. Encryption is used to protect information from all unwanted eyes. Since you are already protected against HTTP clients, the only one(s) able to read it are web server and server administrator

Surely server needs to understand Web.config, so supposing you want to encrypt it you must give server the key.

But then since the administrator (if it's not yourself) has control over server, he has control over Web.config :)

Simple.